# Unable to resume unity3D after pause

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am rather new to c#. I am currently making a pause and resume screen. Pausing seems to work just fine, but the resuming functionality isn't.

I used `Debug.Log` to narrow the problem down to the chunk of code below. When I hit the resume button after pausing, `Paused` get set to `false`, but nothing more happens, it's like if the code never reached the `else` clause.

However, it does work, as before I hit pause, I get "resume" from `Debug.Log`, but whenever I hit pause, I never get that.

```
public static bool Paused;
public void ClickPauseButton()
{
    Paused = true;
    Time.timeScale = 0;
}

public void ClickResumeButton()//works
{
    Paused = false;
    Time.timeScale = 1;
}

void Update()
{
    if(Paused == true)
    {
        showPaused();
        HideUI();
    }
    else //This is the problem... Not a single resume
    {
        ShowUI();
        hidePaused();
        Debug.Log("resume");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Update()` get called?

Comment: My bad, forgot to clarify, this is in unity, so `Update()` is automatically called. "// Update is called once per frame"

Comment: I'd recommend at the top of the `Update` method (just above the `if`) you place: `Debug.Log(string.Format("Paused: {0}", Paused));`. This will both tell you if `Update` is being called, and (if it is) what the value of `Paused` is.

Comment: Why is `Paused` `static`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity, but is it possible `HideUI` would stop your code from calling `Update`?

Comment: Paused will be initialized to false, that's why you're getting "resume", I guess setting the TimeScale to 0 will stop Updating, thus Update is never called

Comment: **Why using `Update` at all?** Just move your code into the `ClickResumeButton` method so it is called event driven without poll checking a bool every frame..

Comment: Are your buttons attached to a Canvas? If so, maybe you are in this situation: https://answers.unity.com/questions/888955/unable-to-click-ui-button-unity-46-when-timescale.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your script with my script which I have given below.

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PausedMenu : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static bool Paused = false;
        public GameObject pauseUI;

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
            {
                if (Paused)
                {
                    ClickResumeButton();
                }
                else
                {
                    ClickPauseButton();
                }
            }
        }

        public void ClickResumeButton()
        {
            pauseUI.SetActive(false);
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
            Paused = false;
        }

        public void ClickPauseButton()
        {
            pauseUI.SetActive(true);
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
            Paused = true;
        }
   }
```

using this you can easily manage your pauseUI.

**Note**: Attach your script to the parent game object. Make sure your game object is in this sequence.
PauseCanvas -> PauseUI -> ResumeButton. you have to give this script to PauseCanvas.
And your pause button is outside of pauseUI.

You can use this sequence which I have given below.

[image]